# Não consigo criar um parágrafo! HTML

Tags: html5, html-tags

Crio um `<p>` e escrevo o parágrafo dentro dele, mas quando abro a página não existem quebramentos de linhas, a frase continua somente em uma linha.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Guilherme P.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="imagem.png">
        <h1 align="center">Essa é a minha primeira página< /h1>
        <p>asadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaasadsadsaddaa< /p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Posta o HTML inteiro por favor

Comment: Sem o código fica complicado. O comportamento normal do <p> é com quebra de linha, algo no seu CSS está alterando isso.

Comment: @Stefano está aí o código, o que poderia estar afetando isso?

Comment: Só tem uma palavra (gigantesca) no seu parágrafo. Não tem onde quebrar.

Comment: @Stefano era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Pronto, separe as palavras do parágrafo precisam conter espaços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<title>Guilherme P.</title>

</head>

<body>

<img src="imagem.png">

<h1 align="center">Essa é a minha primeira página</h1>

<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>

<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>

<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dessa maneira as linhas ficam muito separadas umas das outras

Comment: @GuilhermePassos ao invés de colocar o mesmo parágrafo em tags diferentes, poderia usar um só e utilizar tags `<br>` para fazer as quebras de linha

Comment: ex: 
`<p>
    Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis.<br>
    Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis!
</p>`